# FILTER and REGEXREPLACE cells with Hyperlinks

Tags: google-sheets

I have all the column A with values + Hyperlinks. When I filter these columns, I get only the values of A and miss all the hyperlinks. How Can I keep them?

```
 A       B       C       D 
col1    col2    col3    col4
name1      2       3       4
name2      4       6       8
name3      3       5       7
```

The filter is:

F2 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(FILTER(A:D, C:C="Seen"), " "), "Day on", "Eng. Pending OT"), "Day off", "Eng. Pending OT"))
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xquYG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXREPLACE` will kill the hyperlinks so filter needs to be divided into two parts:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(FILTER(A:G, C:C="Seen"), ), 999, 1), 
 REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(FILTER(B:G, C:C="Seen"), ), "Day on|Day off", "Eng. Pending OT")})
```